# Cypress multiple radio button selection with dynamic value

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

Single radio can be selected using

```
cy.get('[type="radio"]').first().check()
```

If there is multiple radio buttons code on page with dynamic values for buttons.
How to select multi radio buttons in **cypress automation** testing?

Comment: please share the html code for the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation about it : https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/check.html#No-Args
its mentioned you should use  'cy.get('[type="radio"]').check()' in order to select all radio buttons.
hope this helps.[see the image also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Uvp.png)